# Different HitArea based on Device

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a **Panel** that contains two types of elements **MouseArea** and **TouchArea**, when the user moves the cursor, or clicks (**using the mouse**) over the TouchArea I don't want any mouse events to be triggered on the Panel (like `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave` or `MouseMove`)

The way I'm doing it right now is overriding the `HitTestCore` in the **TouchArea** the problem is that I don't know any other way to find out if the user is using a mouse or a stylus except by looking at the `Environment.StackTrace`, which seams like a very bad idea.

```
protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    if (Environment.StackTrace.Contains("Stylus"))
    {
        return base.HitTestCore(hitTestParameters);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So main question is how can I tell what the client is using in a `FrameworkElement` or if such a thing is not possible is there another way to ignore events based on the input device that is used.

Comment: How does these two areas look? I cant imagine this right now...

Comment: @lokusking They're just two rectangles it doesn't matter the way they look I just want to use them as hotspots for the panel or maybe some other container like a button.

Comment: A possible solution might be splitting that one big panel in two smaller ones. One for mouse and one for Touch. Then override the mouse-events in the touch-panel/area

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can get the last input device used from [`System.Windows.Input.InputManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) what I did is:

```
protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    if (InputManager.Current.MostRecentInputDevice is StylusDevice)
    {
        return base.HitTestCore(hitTestParameters);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and now the control is only active if a touch device is used.

Note that `InputManager.Current.MostRecentInputDevice` is `null` by default and it seams to only update on events like `MouseDown` or `TouchDown` and not on `MouseEnter` or `MouseMove`